# In codeigniter Image is uploading into database but not inserting into image folder

Tags: database, image, server, upload, codeigniter-4

$config['upload path'] = './assets/uploads/images';
This code is  not working for my project. Here image is uploading into the database but not inserting into folder so not showing in show page in server.
Folder structure is project name/assets/uploads/images.....try everything but not working required help.
controller

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, codeigniter 4 does not allow uploads outside the 'writable' folder. Make sure that your uploads path is rooted in this folder and that your 'assets' folder is located in the 'writable' folder. It should work.

```
 $config['upload_path'] = WRITEPATH . 'assets/uploads/images';
```